# A nullable expression can't be used as a condition

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, flutter-animation, dart-null-safety

I am getting a "nullable expression" error. The problem is occurring in the following lines:

```dart
left: isSideBarOpenedAsync.data ? 0 : 0,
right: isSideBarOpenedAsync.data ? 0 : screenWidth - 35,
```

Where `isSideBarOpenedAsync` is type `AsyncSnapshot<bool>`

This is the error I'm getting

> A nullable expression can't be used as a condition.
> Try checking that the value isn't `null` before using it as a condition.

Here's the full code for reference

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:solaris/constants.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class SideBar extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _SideBarState createState() => _SideBarState();
}

class _SideBarState extends State<SideBar> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin<SideBar>{
  late AnimationController _animationController;
  late StreamController<bool> isSidebarOpenedStreamController;
  late Stream<bool> isSideBarOpenedStream;
  late StreamSink<bool> isSideBarOpenedSink;
  final _animationDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 500);

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: _animationDuration);
    isSidebarOpenedStreamController = PublishSubject<bool>();
    isSideBarOpenedStream = isSidebarOpenedStreamController.stream;
    isSideBarOpenedSink = isSidebarOpenedStreamController.sink;
  }
  @override
  void dispose(){
  _animationController.dispose();
  isSidebarOpenedStreamController.close();
  isSideBarOpenedSink.close();
  super.dispose();
  }

  void onIconPressed(){
    final animationStatus = _animationController.status;
    final isAnimationCompleted = animationStatus == AnimationStatus.completed;

    if(isAnimationCompleted){
      isSideBarOpenedSink.add(false);
      _animationController.reverse();
    }else{
      isSideBarOpenedSink.add(true);
      _animationController.forward();
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return StreamBuilder<bool>(
      initialData: false,
      stream: isSideBarOpenedStream,
      builder: (context, isSideBarOpenedAsync){
        return AnimatedPositioned(
          duration: _animationDuration,
          top: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          left: isSideBarOpenedAsync.data ? 0 : 0,
          right: isSideBarOpenedAsync.data ? 0 : screenWidth - 35,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: red,
                ),
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment(0,-0.9),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (){
                    onIconPressed();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: 35,
                    height: 110,
                    color: blue,
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: AnimatedIcon(
                      progress: _animationController.view,
                      icon: AnimatedIcons.menu_close,
                      color: white,
                      size: 25,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you know that `isSideBarOpenedAsync.data` will always have a value, you can use a `!` to force the value to not be null.

```dart
isSideBarOpenedAsync.data!
```

This changes the value's type from `bool?` to `bool`.
Your ternary expressions will work with this logic.

**Note:** if `isSideBarOpenedAsync.data` is `null` using a `!` will throw an error, `bool cannot be type null`.

Alternatively, you can provide a value to be used if the value is `null`

```dart
(isSideBarOpenedAsync.data ?? false)
```

If `isSideBarOpenedAsync.data` has a non-null value, it will be referenced. If the value is `null`, `false` will be used instead.

Comment: it should read `(isSideBarOpenedAsync.data ?? false) ? 0 : screenWidth - 35`.

Comment: I was hoping that we have the JavaScript approach which null treated as false, but your clarification helps a lot ...

Comment: Nice @mrgnhnt96 just put ! after the condition like this isSideBarOpenedAsync.data! and everthing worked fine!

Answer (score 6):

***For more clarification about null safety issue just sharing some info here***

There has 3 ways to handle null :

**1. ?. Operator**
- value is Null or not by using simple syntax.

```
data?.variable;
```

**2. ?? Operator** - has Null value and we can also pass default value like

```
variable ?? "";
```

**3. ??= Operator**
- variable is Null or not. If the variable is Null then it will assign a new value to it

```
int x = 5;
x ??= 2;
```

Note : I have solved my same issue using **?.** operator against **bang(!)**

May it help someone. Thanks

Comment: This is the way.

Answer (score 1):

i was getting the same problem : even we are doing sample work from the same place in our code i solved the problem as follows

```
left: isSideBarOpenedAsync.data! ?  0:0, right:isSideBarOpenedAsync.data! ? 0: screenWidth -45,
```

I solved the problem when I tried " data! ? "

Other solutions I tried:

```
left: isSideBarOpenedAsync.data != null && isSideBarOpenedAsync.data ? 0 : 0,
```

right: isSideBarOpenedAsync.data != null && isSideBarOpenedAsync.data ? 0 : screenWidth - 45,

```
left: isSideBarOpenedAsync.hasData && isSideBarOpenedAsync.data! ? 0 : 0,
```

right: isSideBarOpenedAsync.hasData && !isSideBarOpenedAsync.data! ? screenWidth - 45 : 0,

these had happened.